# TypeScript Definition File Cannot Find .d.ts

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

**Context:** I am trying to create a definition file for a [library](https://github.com/messageformat/messageformat/blob/master/lib/messageformat.js) that I am not the author. When consuming the definition file I created, TypeScript mention it cannot find the definition file.

I have tried several things, here are the last three:

**First** try ([inspired by a similar library d.ts](https://github.com/yahoo/intl-messageformat/blob/master/index.d.ts)):

```
declare class MessageFormat {
    constructor(message: string);

    compile: (messageSource: string) => Msg;

}
export type Msg = (params: {}) => string;
export default MessageFormat;
```

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'messageformat'. 'node_modules/messageformat/lib/messageformat.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

**Second** try ([from TypeScript's example to write d.ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-class-d-ts.html))

```
declare class MessageFormat {
    constructor(message: string);

    compile: (messageSource: string) => MessageFormat.Msg;

}
declare namespace MessageFormat {
    type Msg = (params: {}) => string;
}
export = MessageFormat;
```

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'messageformat'. 'node_modules/messageformat/lib/messageformat.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

**Third** try ([from a GitHub question](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23185))

```
declare module "messageformat" {
    export type Msg = (params: {}) => string;
    export interface MessageFormat {
        new(message: string): any;
        compile: (messageSource: string) => Msg;
    }
}
```

> Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.

**Code:** The three tentatives are in this repo: https://github.com/MrDesjardins/importdefinitionfiles

Can someone give me a pointer about what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you importing the module / trying to invoke `new` with it?

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh The third-party module is from `npm` and imported with `import MessageFormat from "messageformat";`

Comment: Not sure why you suddenly switched to an interface with new(...) method in there in the last example. Changing that to `class` with a `constructor` is correct. Also, looking at the source the constructor signature should be: `constructor(locale: string|string[]|Object)` and the Object should be replaced with a proper interface as well.

Comment: Also, no need for `export` keywords in normal type definitions inside ambient module declarations. Everything is exported & declared by default.

Comment: The one export you do need at the end, since `MessageFormat` is the default export in this module is `export = MessageFormat;`

Comment: @zenmumbler The "second try" is what you described. It uses `constructor` and it exports. It produces: Could not find a declaration file for module 'messageformat'

Comment: @PatrickDesjardins Well, the combination is the correct one, a class inside a module declaration. The 2nd try is just a declaration of a class and a namespace. TS needs to know what to resolve the module name to, just having a d.ts with a certain file name inside your project folder isn't enough. Place the export I mentioned _inside_ the module decl. Tested this locally.

Comment: @zenmumbler Oh yeah that makes sense! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me, inside some d.ts file in your project, filename is not relevant. *DO* make sure "messageformat" is the actual name of the node module, otherwise your packager will fail.

```
declare module "messageformat" {
    type Msg = (params: {}) => string;
    class MessageFormat {
        constructor(locale: string | string[] | Object);
        compile(messageSource: string): Msg;
    }
    export = MessageFormat;
}
```

Now, in some other module:

```
import MessageFormat from "messageformat";
const mf = new MessageFormat("en");
const thing = mf.compile("blarb");
```

Comment: You are right, it works. I am a little bit confused about why the TypeScript's example on the official website doesn't have the module with quotes like this example.